# Confusions on how to express this theorem

Tags: math-mode

I'm having trouble latexing the following theorem, it seems and looks this was produced by asmart, i'm a beginner when it comes to latex and i'm having trouble expressing this.

[image]

My initial attempt was as follows:

```
$$
\sigma_{n}(x) = \sigma_{n}[f](x) = s_{o} + \cdot \cdot \cdot s_{n-1}(x) / N - \frac{1}{2}a_{o} + \sum(1 - n/k)(a_{n}cosn(x) + b_{n}sin(n(x) = \int_{}^{} f(x + t) F_{k}(t) dt = \int_{}^{} f(x+t) + f(x-t)/2 F_{k}(t)dt
$$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5):

The document seems to be `amsbook` with some tweaks:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

% we want equation numbers to be reset at sections
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
% we want equation numbers to contain the chapter number
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}} %

% theorems should share the equation counter
\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\setcounter{chapter}{2}% just for the example

\chapter{Test}

\setcounter{section}{1}% just for the example

\section{Test}

\setcounter{equation}{2}% just for the example

\begin{theorem}
Let $f$ be $2\pi$-periodic and integrable over a period. Then, for all $k$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sigma_{k}(x)
&= \sigma_{k}[f](x)=\frac{s_{0}(x)+\dots+s_{k-1}(x)}{k} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}a_{0}+\sum_{n=1}^{k-1} \Bigl(1-\frac{n}{k}\Bigr)(a_{n}\cos nx+b_{n}\sin nx) \\
&= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x\pm t)F_{k}(t)\,dt
 = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{f(x+t)+f(x-t)}{2}F_{k}(t)\,dt
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

The `\setcounter` instructions are just to match the picture, don't use them in a production version.

Note a couple of improvements:

1. `\,` in front of `dt`;
2. alignment at `=` signs;
3. the trailing `\forall k` is part of the statement, where it belongs.

[image]

Comment: you could have said `\numberwithin{section}{chapter}` instead of explicitly resetting `\thesection`.  moving the `\forall k` into the text avoided a nearly overfull line, which is a nice touch.